# how to change property mapping in asp core with attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to change the property name so that I can send my asp core controller method this this json

```
{
    "Season": 1
}
```

and map to my C# property

```
public long SeasonNumber {get; set;}
```

in old WCF I used to be able to map properties with

```
[DataMember("Season")]
```

is there an equivalent for asp core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient

Still is DataMember? Just need to add reference to required library.
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll